# Error with serializable class

Tags: java, android, objectoutputstream

I have a java server that sends some data through a socket to a client developed in android.
The data that sent is serialized...and at the client side when trying to read from the ObjectInputStream I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servers.Coordinate    
 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:237)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2604) 
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1860)
 java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:840)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2080)
 java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:943)
 java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2299)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2254)
 at com.Server_1.ClientThread_special.run(ClientThread_special.java:30)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: servers.Coordinate
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servers.Coordinate in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02e18
 at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
```

Now here is my code on the server side:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("S-a conectat clientul de monitorizare!");


        os=new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        try{
        while(true){
            coord=(Coordinate)queue.take();
            System.out.println(coord.getLat());
        os.writeObject(coord);

        os.flush();

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

On the client side I have this:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, serverPort);

        is=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());



            try{
                while(!stop){

            coord=(Coordinate)is.readObject();

            System.out.println("Date de la clientul de monitorizare:"+coord.getLat());

            }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        is.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

And here is my serializable class I have it both on the client side and in the server side:

```
 public class Coordinate implements Serializable{

  private final double lon;

  private final double lat;

  private final int workerId;



  public Coordinate(double lat, double lon, int workerId) {

    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;

    this.workerId=workerId;
  }

  public double getLon() {
    return lon;
  }

  public double getLat() {
    return lat;
  }
  public int getwId(){
      return workerId;
  }


}
```

---

An instance of this class is what I'm sending through the socket.

---

EDIT:

on server I have the following :

package servers;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Coordinate implements Serializable{

```
  private final double lon;

  private final double lat;

  private final int workerId;



  public Coordinate(double lat, double lon, int workerId) {

    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;

    this.workerId=workerId;
  }

  public double getLon() {
    return lon;
  }

  public double getLat() {
    return lat;
  }
  public int getwId(){
      return workerId;
  }


}
```

on the client side I have the following:

package com.Server_1;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Coordinate implements Serializable{

```
  private final double lon;

  private final double lat;

  private final int workerId;

  public Coordinate(double lat, double lon, int workerId) {

    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;

    this.workerId=workerId;
  }

  public double getLon() {
    return lon;
  }

  public double getLat() {
    return lat;
  }
  public int getwId(){
      return workerId;
  }


}
```

I don't understand how could I change the package to be the same on both of them!!!!!!

Comment: You didn't show the package on the Coordinate class. What is the package? Is it the same on the server and the client?

Comment: But there are two different application How could I put the same package on the coordinate class?

Comment: I can't understand why you think that you can use the same package name in the client. Just copy and paste the class from the server project to the client project. That's it! (Or better yet, place the class in a common project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name of the class must be the same on the server and the client. I would also add serialVersionUID to the class. [Implementing Serializable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45)

Comment: You **must** use the same package name in both the client and server. I don't understand why you are giving the class a different package name in the client code.